# Remove a specific html node from a set of nodes

Tags: r, rvest

I want to scrape the reports from https://paidabribe.com/reports/paid in R. Everything works quit good with my following code besides some reports contain an embedded element under the report which is part of the CSS node of the report text.

For example https://paidabribe.com/reports/paid?page=10 has one embedded text "How to get a LPG gas connection".

Therefore I end up with character vectors of different length for different pages depending on the amount of reports with embedded elements. My question is how can I remove this specific element of the node and just scrape the text of the report

SelectorGadget told me that this node can be called by using "em". So I tried the following :

```
#DO NOT RUN
scraper <- function(pages){
bribe <- read_html(paste("http://ipaidabribe.com/reports/paid?page", pages, sep = "=")) 
bribe <- bribe %>% html_nodes("em") 
bribe <- xml_remove(bribe)
all.nodes <- c(".paid-amount span", ".date", ".location", ".transaction a", ".body-copy-lg")
map(all.nodes, ~ html_nodes(bribe, .x) %>% html_text())
}

pages <- seq(10, 50, by = 10)
bribe.test <- map(pages,~scraper(.x))
```

The problem here seems to be that the embedded text can't be selected using the node "em". So how can I remove this embedded node.

MWE (Produces a list of the scraped content. As you can see the vector of the reports sometime differ in length compared to the other character vectors. :

````
scraper <- function(pages){
bribe <- read_html(paste("http://ipaidabribe.com/reports/paid?page", pages, sep = "=")) 
all.nodes <- c(".paid-amount span", ".date", ".location", ".transaction a", ".body-copy-lg")
map(all.nodes, ~ html_nodes(bribe, .x) %>% html_text())
}

pages <- seq(10, 50, by = 10)
bribe.test <- map(pages,~scraper(.x)) 
```R
````

Comment: When I look at the page source for that page I'm not even finding any <em> tags. Is it possible that the page renders differently in different browsers? What are you specifically trying to remove and what are you trying to keep? An example would help.

Comment: Also, instead of xml remove you can often use the css `":not(em)"` selector.

Comment: I want to remove this : http://prntscr.com/qlv07b

Comment: I already tried to do it with `":not(em)"` but it did not work.

Comment: And I want to keep only this http://prntscr.com/qlv65p. It's possible that you do not find any <em> element on some pages. To be precise : You will find the tags only on those 
pages which have reports with an embedded text at the end of the report. An example can bee seen in my first comment about what node I want to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately just removing the  node doesn't seem to be enough, since its text appears to be replicated in its parent node.

What you can do instead is to write blank contents into the  node, then strip out empty text strings from your answer.

```r
scraper <- function(pages)
{
    bribe <- read_html(paste("http://ipaidabribe.com/reports/paid?page", pages, sep = "="))
    bribe <- xml_children(bribe)
    ems <- html_nodes(bribe, "em")
    xml_text(ems) <- ""
    all.nodes <- c(".paid-amount span", ".date", ".location", ".transaction a",
                    ".body-copy-lg")
    map(all.nodes, ~ html_nodes(bribe, .x) %>% 
                     html_text() %>% 
                     {grep("[[:alnum:]]", ., value = T)})
}

pages <- seq(10, 50, by = 10)
bribe.test <- map(pages,~scraper(.x))
```

This gives a list of text without the `<em>` tagged content.

Comment: The code runs but, the list still contains the  `<em>` tagged content :
`[4] "\r\n                    \r\n                      \r\n                      How to get a LPG gas connection\r\n                    \r\n `

Comment: @mugdi I think that's because you have only removed the <em> node, but not the elements which contain the em node as a child, so the text is still included. See my updated answer for the solution.

Comment: Thanks for that try. But sadly it does not remove all embedded signatures and unfortunatly removes some of the other content as well. It seems there is no other way than using regex.